# Bootstrap not working properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface

I am using a collapse on the 'main' id but it doesn't collapse when the page is loaded. Once you click it collapses and works fine. I am not using 'collapse in' so I don't know why this is happening.

And when I click on the header the container expands and then it kind of awkwardly readjusts. Please check the code and hopefully you'll understand my concerns.

Also what I'm trying is not working. I have created two columns in the header row. But those divs do not work properly the the div with col-xs-2 flows to the bottom of the other column. I want them side by side. The same thing is happening with the two buttons I am using in the 'main'.
I hope this explains all my problems. Please check the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>ABC</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<script src ="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src ="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


         <div class="container" id="container">
                <div class="row" id="header">

                    <div class="col-xs-10" id="logo" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main">ABC</div>

                    <div class="col-xs-2" id="arrow-down">Arrow</div>            

               </div>

               <div class="row" class="collapse" id="main">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6" id="button1">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active">Detail1</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6" id="button2">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary disabled">Detail2</button>

                            </div>
                        </div>
               </div>

               </div>

        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS part

```
*{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
#container{
    width:450px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: auto;

}

#header{
    background-color: #6C6D70;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #2DB5AB;
    height: 50px;
}

#logo{

    padding:10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#arrow-down{

    color:black;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 15px 10px 10px 10px;

    border: 1px;
}

#main{
    padding: 10px;
}

#video-detail{


}

#buttons{

    padding:10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add CSS class "collapse" to the #main element

```
<div class="row collapse" class="collapsed" id="main">
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yru9hf7t/

Comment: Yes that works thanks. That solved the collapse in problem. Can you help me with the other problems as mentioned in the question?

Comment: I checked the code you provided on Jsfiddle and I think its the same. However I copied your code and tried to run it. I am still having the same problems. i.e. The col-xs-2  is flowing below the col-xs-10 not side by side and the buttons are also not side by side. Although the code runs fine of Jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help

**Html**

```
<div class="container" id="container">
    <div class="row" id="header">
        <div class="col-xs-10" id="logo" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main">ABC</div>
        <div class="col-xs-2" id="arrow-down">Arrow</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row collapse" class="collapsed" id="main">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="row mystyle">
                <div class="col-xs-6" id="button1">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active">Detail1</button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6" id="button2">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary disabled">Detail2</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#container {
    width:450px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: auto;
}
#header {
    background-color: #6C6D70;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #2DB5AB;
    height: 50px;
}
#logo {
    padding:10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
#arrow-down {
    color:black;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 15px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: 1px;
}
.mystyle{
    padding:20px;
}
#buttons {
    padding:10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Working fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/ryqgm0ra/